# Strategies to work backward and forward when doing natural deduction proof

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

In forall x: Calgary, by P. D. Magnus, p. 153, there is this question:

B. Formulate strategies for working backward and forward from $\mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}$.

**Working forward**

Having $\mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ as a premise, I would want to eliminate the biconditional. So, I would need to find A and justify it using a conditional. Then, I could use $\leftrightarrow E$ to get $\mathcal{B}$.

I need to use Elimination Rules when working forward and Introduction Rules, backward.

Is something similar to this what the book asks ? Not sure if he is referring to working forward from premises or $\mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is a sentence that appear somewhere in the proof (or subproof).

Comment: Thank you @user726n98e09t. Super useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is something similar to this what the book asks ? Not sure if he is referring to working forward from premises or $\mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is a sentence that appear somewhere in the proof (or subproof).

Yes, that is it.  You want strategies that take $A\leftrightarrow B$ as one of the premises, assumptions, or derivations and *work forward* towards deriving some target.

The rules of *biconditional elimination* and *conditional elimination*, along with having one of the equivalents ($A, B$), will build such a strategy.

---

Likewise you want strategies where $A\leftrightarrow B$ is the target, and *work backward* to derive that target.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. In case I have $A\leftrightarrow B$ as one of the premises, the only thing I need to find is $A$ or $B$. Then, I can use _biconditional elimination_. Is it correct ?

Comment: @F.Zer What does the rule of biconditional elimation say?  There's often some symbol like "$\vdash$" or a set of dots, or a line, or a phrase like "we may infer", which separates what you start with before using a rule and what you get when you use that rule.  In the statement of such rules, the variables stand for any well-formed formulas.  Thus, you can use biconditional elimination anytime you have a well-formed biconditional formula.